# Library is imported but python says not defined

Tags: python

so I'm using this code in Python:

```
import sys

def main:
    stdout.write("\r" + dsp)    
    stdout.flush() 

main()
```

But Python keep telling me: NameError: global name 'stdout' is not defined
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already tried to diagnose the problem?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: I would strongly suggest giving the [Google Developer's Ptyhon Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) a go if you don't want your next question to get downvoted into oblivion as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use

```
import sys

def main:
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + dsp)    
    sys.stdout.flush() 

main()
```

to use stdout like you did, you either need to do :

```
from sys import stdout
```

or

```
from sys import *
```

but in my opinion neither of them are a great idea, as the "pollute" your modules namespace